# meaning of address

Tags: vocabulary

> The justices must `_18_` doubts about the court’s legitimacy by making themselves accountable to the code of conduct.
>
> ```
> 18. [A]suppress   [B]exploit   [C]address   [D]ignore
> ```

The answer is `C`, but I do not know what's the meaning of address here. 
I think `A` is reasonable in the meaning.

Comment: Dictionaries will tell you: [To direct the efforts or attention of (oneself)](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/address)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dictionaries will tell you: [To direct the efforts or attention of (oneself)](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/address)

So in this case

The justices has to make sure they behave to avoid any doubts about the legitimacy of the court